# Mounting the Drive to the Raspberry Pi and changing DIR ownership

Tags: raspberry-pi, root, chown, ownership

so, after having followed this guide here `https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-mount-usb-drive/`

I've ended up with an automatically mounted external fat32 drive but now the ownership of that folder it is mounted into has changed from pi to root and I cannot change it back to pi or plex or anything using chown command thus making it impossible to add or delete files from this drive. Any suggestions?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: 1. yes the link will exist tomorrow, it's been there for 2 years almost. Ok what I've done so far is this
sudo blkid /dev/sda1
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/usb1
sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/usb1
sudo nano /etc/fstab
UUID=[UUID] /mnt/usb1 [TYPE] defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail,noatime 0 0
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo mount -a

Rebooted the OS and the drive is WORKING, I just cannot add or delete files, only read them as the ownership is under ROOT and not PI

Answer (score 0):

Read `man mount`. There's an ExFAT section that describes `uid=` and `gid=` options.

You can find your UID and GID with the `id` command.

Comment: I've found UID and type it is mounted properly. It is working, I just need to change the drive ownership from root to username and I am not allowed to do this with CHOWN